# Hibernate Exception: Missing Column (column exists)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Okay, so within the database we have a table called distributionCompanies, created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `distributionCompanies` (
    `distributionCompanyID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `distributionCompanyName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (distributionCompanyID)
);
```

I'm trying to map this table to a class using Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distributionCompanies")
public class DistributionCompany implements DatabaseObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "distributionCompanyID", length = 11, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int distributionCompanyID;
....
```

However, when running, I hit this issue:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: distributionCompanyID_distributionCompanyID in database2.distributionCompanies
```

This isn't the only table in the database, and I've managed to map other classes successfully using the same method, so I'm a little stumped as to why this is causing an issue.

Thank you for your time,
Samuel Smith

EDIT: In response to Xavi's comment, I temporarily removed another mapping for the column, and the error went away, so the bad-egg probably lays in the following code:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = DistributionCompany.class)
@JoinTable(name = "distributionCompanies", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =    "distributionCompanyID", nullable = false) })
private int distributionCompanyID;
```

Comment: It seems Hibernate is looking for a column named `distributionCompanyID_distributionCompanyID`. Does this entity have other mappings (e.g. associations with other entities)? Have you tried leaving only the mapping for this column to make sure it is the one that's bringing the error up? If it works fine with only the mapping for `distributionCompanyId`, please post the complete mapping of the entity.

Comment: What @Generatedvalue strategy you want to use. Is it really the DEFAULT which is AUTO ?

Comment: @XaviLópez - You have lead me down a correct path, see my edit. Thank you :)

Comment: @Samuel indeed, I was already writing an answer with regard to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate is looking for a column named `distributionCompanyID_distributionCompanyID` in your `distributionCompanies` table.

This is probably due to a `ToOne` association mapping towards this table without `@JoinColum`.

From [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1046):

> The @JoinColumn attribute is optional, the default value(s) is like in one to one, the concatenation of the name of the relationship in the owner side, _ (underscore), and the name of the primary key column in the owned side. In this example company_id because the property name is company and the column id of Company is id.

If you've got a `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` association mapping in another entity, this would explain why Hibernate is looking for such a column.

**EDIT** Seeing the association mapping you posted, it looks like it should be:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = DistributionCompany.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "distributionCompanyID")
private DistributionCompany distributionCompany;
```

The `@JoinTable` annotation is used to specify a join table (that means an intermediate table used to model many-to-many associations). And the point of mapping an association would be to dispose of the mapped object instance (in this case a `DistributionCompany`, not just a `distributionCompanyId`).