# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, zk

---

hei i have spring 3 & hibernate 4, when running program i haven error like this, what must i do

```html
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:ZKBeanValidation' did not find a matching property.
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8089"]
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:46 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1019 ms
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Okt 17, 2014 6:30:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: system in addressbook.userprofile
```

---

Answer (score 1):

"nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: system in addressbook.userprofile"

Try checking for a missing column in addressbook.userprofile.  It's looking for a column called "system".  Or, try checking your relation annotations in your hibernate mapping file.  It's difficult to say more with out seeing some code.

Here is a similar issue that may help you:
[Hibernate Exception: Missing Column (column exists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237514/hibernate-exception-missing-column-column-exists)